# EF Code First Composition, Table Mapping, simulating Complex Types

Tags: database, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

I have a complex data model (for EF 4.1 code first) that uses composition (many 1-to-1's) to achieve benefits similar to multiple inheritance. But I have a problem to solve, hopefully with mapping.

1. I need to reduce the number of tables (not entities) to simulate
   successful multiple inheritance.
2. I cannot replace the 1-to-1 composition classes with complex types
   because I will use Dynamic Data as an admin back-end and DD doesn't
   work with complex types.
3. Table-per-hierarchy does not seem it would help here because of the
   simulated multiple inheritance.
4. Table-per-type would give way too many tables.

I think there is something called "entity splitting". And I think I basically need the opposite of it? I wonder if what I want is even possible... basically simulating complex types by mapping model components more than once.. it sounds impossible. Should I just scrap the composition approach? I could always group properties with attributes or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opposite of entity splitting is called table splitting and it [is really possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390172/how-to-map-table-splitting-in-ef-code-first) but it has [one big problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491619/how-to-separate-large-table-into-multiple-discrete-types-using-ef-code-first/8493905#8493905) happening only in EF code first.

Comment: thank you for the quick reply! If I am trying to use a single class in multiple classes (to simulate multi-inherit) how can that component class be mapped more than once (since multiple tables will need it)? For example, if type `SchedulingInfo` has 1-to-1 with type `Sale` AND `Order` AND `DonutBreak` but those 3 types should be 3 different tables. Can `SchedulingInfo` be mapped more than once to all 3 tables without splitting it? If not then I might as well flatten the model?

Comment: No single class can be mapped only once. The only exceptions are mapped inheritance and splitting scenarios.

Comment: Ok. So if I can't use complex types in DyanmicData, then the best solution is table-per-type and repeat each property on each class that needs it? Or single inheritance?