# EF6 failing to build model for Table Split/Shared Primary Key + Base class?

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, domain-driven-design, shared-primary-key, table-splitting

**The problem**

I'm trying to share a large table (200+fields) around ~7 entities using table splitting as per [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20966328/ef6-table-splitting-vs-shared-primary-key-for-multiple-splits).

EF6 requires navigation properties not just from the primary model to the child models, but between all the child models (which sucks).

**Manual solution**

This can be done manually:

```
public class Franchise
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual FranchiseEntity Entity { get; set; }
    public virtual FranchiseMiscellaneous Miscellaneous { get; set; }
}

[Table("Franchise")]
public class FranchiseEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual FranchiseEntity Entity { get; set; } // Ignored, but relevant when inheritance involved, below...
    public virtual FranchiseMiscellaneous Miscellaneous { get; set; }
}

[Table("Franchise")]
public class FranchiseMiscellaneous
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual FranchiseEntity Entity { get; set;
    public virtual FranchiseMiscellaneous Miscellaneous { get; set; }  // Ignored, but relevant when inheritance involved, below...
}
```

With fluent mappings:

```
public class FranchiseMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Franchise>
{
    public FranchiseMapping()
    {
        HasRequired(x => x.Entity).WithRequiredPrincipal();
        HasRequired(x => x.Miscellaneous).WithRequiredPrincipal();
    }
}

public class FranchiseEntityMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<FranchiseEntity>
{
    public FranchiseEntityMapping()
    {
        Ignore(x => x.Entity);
        HasRequired(x => x.Miscellaneous).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Entity);
    }
}

public class FranchiseMiscellaneousMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<FranchiseMiscellaneous>
{
    public FranchiseMiscellaneousMapping()
    {
        Ignore(x => x.Miscellaneous);
    }
}
```

THIS WORKS. But it won't this will not scale up well with 7+ models.

**Attempt to improve #1**

I'd like to improve through Inheritance + DRY principle:

```
public abstract class SharedFranchiseIdBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual FranchiseEntity Entity { get; set; }
    public virtual FranchiseMiscellaneous Miscellaneous { get; set; }
}

public class Franchise : SharedFranchiseIdBase { ... }

public class FranchiseEntity : SharedFranchiseIdBase { ... }

public class FranchiseMiscellaneous : SharedFranchiseIdBase { ... }

// Maybe generalize the mapping code too...
```

But this FAILS on first request with "Sequence contains more than one matching element":

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one matching element
Result StackTrace:  
at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Navigation.NavigationPropertyConfiguration.ConfigureDependentBehavior(AssociationType associationType, EdmModel model, EntityTypeConfiguration entityTypeConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Navigation.NavigationPropertyConfiguration.Configure(NavigationProperty navigationProperty, EdmModel model, EntityTypeConfiguration entityTypeConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigureAssociations(EntityType entityType, EdmModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Configure(EntityType entityType, EdmModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntities(EdmModel model)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo)
   at System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext internalContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   ... // my test query function
```

**Attempt to improve #2**

I thought I could declare them abstract, so at least the programmers are forced to implement the correct members (still sucks to re-declare on each derived class):

```
public abstract class SharedFranchiseIdBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public abstract FranchiseEntity Entity { get; set; }
    public abstract FranchiseMiscellaneous Miscellaneous { get; set; }
}

public class Franchise : SharedFranchiseIdBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public override FranchiseEntity Entity { get; set; }
    public override FranchiseMiscellaneous Miscellaneous { get; set; }
}
//etc for other classes
```

But this fails when the same error. Huh?? The class definitions are IDENTICAL as the working copy except that they are declared "override" instead of "virtual". It's as if E/F is indexing on PropertyInfos or something without regard for the PropertyInfo.ReflectedType

**Attempt to improve #3**

I could enforce the pattern using an interface, but this is less preferable as the interface has to be declared on each class which is starting to look pretty weird:

```
public class Franchise : SharedFranchiseIdBase, ISharedFranchiseId { ... }

public class FranchiseEntity : SharedFranchiseIdBase, ISharedFranchiseId { ... }

public class FranchiseMiscellaneous : SharedFranchiseIdBase, ISharedFranchiseId { ... }
```

**Huh?**

Is this a bug in E/F, that it struggles to treat properties on the base class identical to those on the derived classes?

Apologies for the long-winded explanation, it's the summary of this morning's entire investigation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the end I have decided to adopt the manual solution as I could not get any of the improvement attempts to work.

The code & models aren't elegant, but at the end of the day it performs OK. I've implemented the pattern in 3 areas and it's performing as required, in the Domain and at the SQL layer.

To ease the pain and provide developers with a consistent way to work with this pattern, I created this interface to enforce all the relationships:

```
public interface ISharedFranchiseId
{
    FranchiseBilling Billing { get; set; }
    FranchiseCompliance Compliance { get; set; }
    FranchiseLeadAllocation LeadAllocation { get; set; }
    FranchiseMessaging Messaging { get; set; }
    FranchiseMiscellaneous Miscellaneous { get; set; }
    FranchiseSignup Signup { get; set; }
}
```

So each of the models sharing the primary key have these properties (the annoying bit):

```
public class FranchiseBilling/Compliance/etc : ISharedFranchiseId
{
    // Properties implemented on this model
    #region Navigations to other entities sharing primary key
    public virtual FranchiseBilling Billing { get; set; }
    public virtual FranchiseCompliance Compliance { get; set; }
    public virtual FranchiseLeadAllocation LeadAllocation { get; set; }
    public virtual FranchiseMessaging Messaging { get; set; }
    public virtual FranchiseMiscellaneous Miscellaneous { get; set; }
    public virtual FranchiseSignup Signup { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

And configure via Fluent API as follows (the painful bit):

```
// Franchise = the "primary/parent" model
public class FranchiseMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Franchise>
{
    public FranchiseMapping()
    {
        HasRequired(x => x.Billing).WithRequiredPrincipal();
        HasRequired(x => x.Compliance).WithRequiredPrincipal();
        HasRequired(x => x.LeadAllocation).WithRequiredPrincipal();
        HasRequired(x => x.Miscellaneous).WithRequiredPrincipal();
        HasRequired(x => x.Messaging).WithRequiredPrincipal();
        HasRequired(x => x.Signup).WithRequiredPrincipal();
    }
}

// Now each "child" model gets link to all the others. We only need links going one way,
// So each model links to the ones listed below.
// This makes it easy to implement an extra child model down the track as we just
// insert the configuration it here and copy from the next one.
public class FranchiseBillingMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<FranchiseBilling>
{
    public FranchiseBillingMapping()
    {
        Ignore(x => x.Billing);
        HasRequired(x => x.Compliance).WithRequiredDependent(x => x.Billing);
        HasRequired(x => x.LeadAllocation).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Billing);
        HasRequired(x => x.Miscellaneous).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Billing);
        HasRequired(x => x.Messaging).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Billing);
        HasRequired(x => x.Signup).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Billing);
    }
}

public class FranchiseComplianceMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<FranchiseCompliance>
{
    public FranchiseComplianceMapping()
    {
        Ignore(x => x.Compliance);
        HasRequired(x => x.LeadAllocation).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Compliance);
        HasRequired(x => x.Miscellaneous).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Compliance);
        HasRequired(x => x.Messaging).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Compliance);
        HasRequired(x => x.Signup).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Compliance);
    }
}

public class FranchiseLeadAllocationMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<FranchiseLeadAllocation>
{
    public FranchiseLeadAllocationMapping()
    {
        Ignore(x => x.LeadAllocation);
        HasRequired(x => x.Miscellaneous).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.LeadAllocation);
        HasRequired(x => x.Messaging).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.LeadAllocation);
        HasRequired(x => x.Signup).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.LeadAllocation);
    }
}

public class FranchiseeMiscellaneousMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<FranchiseeMiscellaneous>
{
    public FranchiseeMiscellaneousMapping()
    {
        Ignore(x => x.Miscellaneous);
        HasRequired(x => x.Messaging).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Miscellaneous);
        HasRequired(x => x.Signup).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Miscellaneous);
    }
}

public class FranchiseMessagingMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<FranchiseMessaging>
{
    public FranchiseMessagingMapping()
    {
        Ignore(x => x.Messaging);
        HasRequired(x => x.Signup).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Messaging);
    }
}

public class FranchiseSignupMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<FranchiseSignup>
{
    public FranchiseSignupMapping()
    {
        Ignore(x => x.Signup);
    }
}
```